# daily delete file log4net in C#

Tags: log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

`i want to log by date and save upto 7 old logs
I have configured like this but it doesn't delete old log files
give me the solution

```
\<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender"\>
\<file value="logs/application.log" /\>
\<appendToFile value="true" /\>
\<rollingStyle value="Date" /\>
\<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" /\> \<!-- Format thời gian trong tên file log --\>
\<maxSizeRollBackups value="10" /\> \<!-- Số lượng file log cũ được lưu lại --\>
\<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout"\>
\<conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" /\>
\</layout\>
\</appender\>
\<appender name="ProcessAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender"\>
\<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="..\\Log\\%date{yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}\_vtracking.txt"/\>
\<appendToFile value="true"/\>
\<rollingStyle value="Composite"/\>
\<maxSizeRollBackups value="1"/\>
\<maximumFileSize value="10MB"/\>
\<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd-HHmm"/\>
\<staticLogFileName value="false"/\>
\<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout"\>
\<conversionPattern value="%m%n"/\>
\</layout\>
\</appender\>
```

I checked, when the new day is turned on, but the log file of the previous day is not deleted, the log of the new day is recorded in another log file.